# CollectionView in the storyboard is overwriting the cell size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a collection view that has cells that change size depending on what size the user has selected: Small, medium, large. I have the protocol UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout and the delegate function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
```

The function correctly sets the size of the area needed for the cell but doesn't resize the cell itself.

here is what my view looks like when the cells have been set to the small setting:

[image: CollectionView With Small Cells]

Here is the view with the default size:

[image: Standard collectionview cells]

As you can see the space for the cell changes but the cell size doesn't change.

In the storyboard, whatever the cell size is set to, is what the size will be regardless of what I do in the code. Does anyone know how I can override this:

[image: storyboard]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

#### EDIT

The delegate function is being called. the size is changed on a different page. The size is stored as a value in a singleton, the delegate function decides what size to use based on that value. Here is the delegate function:

> ```
> func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
>                     layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
>                     sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
>  //   if self.collectionView == collectionView {
>         let viewHeight = collectionView.frame.height
>         let smallSize = (viewHeight / 4) - 20
>         let mediumSize = (viewHeight / 2) - 20
>         let largeSize = viewHeight - 20
>         switch gridSquareSize {
>         case .small:
>             return CGSize(width: smallSize, height: smallSize)
>         case .standard:
>             return CGSize(width: mediumSize, height: mediumSize)
>         case .large:
>             return CGSize(width: largeSize, height: largeSize)
>         }
>     //}
> }
> ```

#### EDIT 2:

Here is the function that sets up the cell:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "galleryCell", for: indexPath)
            as! GalleryCell
        
        cell.layoutIfNeeded()
        
        
        switch SettingsModel.instance.currentGridSquareSize {
        case .small:
            cell.galleryName.font = cell.galleryName.font.withSize(12)
            break
        case .standard:
            cell.galleryName.font = cell.galleryName.font.withSize(24)
            break
        case .large:
            cell.galleryName.font = cell.galleryName.font.withSize(36)
            break
        }
        cell.isHidden = false
        cell.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        cell.plusIcon.isHidden = true
        cell.topLeftImage.isHidden = false
        cell.galleryName.textColor = UIColor(red: 45, green: 64, blue: 83, alpha: 1)
        cell.topLeftImage.image = UIImage(named: "PlaceholderImage")
        cell.delete.isHidden = !isInEditMode
        let position = indexPath.row
        if position == mGalleriesList.count {
            if isInEditMode {
                cell.background.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
                cell.galleryName.text = "Add new gallery"
                cell.galleryName.textColor = UIColor.white
                cell.plusIcon.isHidden = false
                cell.topLeftImage.isHidden = true
                cell.delete.isHidden = true
            }
            else {
                cell.isHidden = true
            }
        }
        else {
            let gallery = mGalleriesList[position]
            cell.data = gallery
            cell.plusIcon.isHidden = true
            if let galleryName = gallery.galleryName {
                cell.galleryName.text = galleryName
            }
            var mediaEntries = [MediaEntry]()
            for entry in gallery.mediaEntries {
                if let deleted = entry.deleted {
                    if !deleted {
                        mediaEntries.append(entry)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    mediaEntries.append(entry)
                }
            }
            if mediaEntries.count > 0 {
                if let downloadUrl = mediaEntries[0].downloadUrl {
                    setImage(storageUrl: downloadUrl, imageView: cell.topLeftImage, placeholder: placeholder!, cropToBounds: false)
                }
            }
        }
      

        return cell
    }
```

Here is also a screenshot of the cell inside the storyboard:

[image]

Hope this additional information helps

Comment: did you reload collection view on changes of size?

Comment: Did the delegate method getting called at all?

Comment: Have you set the delegate of the collection view? Make sure you call `collectionView.reloadData()` after you've recalculated the width/height. Also note that the implementation of the delegate function will most likely not be represented in the storyboard. Run your application to see whether or not it works.

Comment: I have edited my question with the answer to your queries.

Comment: Can you share us the creation of `UICollectionView` ?

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh have updated the post with the relevant information

Comment: Update your Background View constraints like 
`View.leading = View.leading
View.top = View.top
View.trailing = View.trailing
View.bottom= View.bottom`

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh I have tried updating my constraints inside the cellForItemAt function but nothing changed, I tried cell.view.updateConstraints() as well as changing the constants of the constraints and then calling layoutIfNeeded().